# In Extjs 4, why is my firing of custom event om image el not working?

Tags: extjs, custom-events

Update 2: This confirms the cpuchartclicked event is being fired, because the alert('hello') works. What I need is to be able to respond to that event in my controller.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'image',
        itemId: 'graphiteChartCPU',
        src: '',
        listeners:{
            'afterrender':function (comp) {
                comp.getEl().on('click', function (el) {
                    this.fireEvent('cpuchartclicked');
                }, this);
            },
            'cpuchartclicked':function () {
                alert('hello');
            }
        }
    }
```

### ]

Update: With the following, I am setting the scope for the on click handler. fireEvent() seems to be working now, but still not hearing the event in controller.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'image',
        itemId: 'graphiteChartCPU',
        src: '',
        listeners:{
            'afterrender':function (comp) {
                comp.getEl().on('click', function (el) {
                    alert('on click handler');
                    this.fireEvent('cpuchartclicked');
                }, this);
            }
        }
    }
]

// Listen Application Event
me.application.on({
    cpuchartclicked: me.onChartClicked,
    scope: me
});
```

---

I'm trying to fire a custom event on an image el so when the image is clicked the controller hears the event.

But I get an error cmp.fireEvent() is not a function?

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'image',
    itemId: 'graphiteChartCPU',
    src: '',
    listeners:{
        'afterrender':function (comp) {
        comp.getEl().on('click', function (el) {
        el.fireEvent('cpuchartclicked');
        });
        }
    }
}]

me.application.on({
    cpuchartclicked: this.onChartClicked,
    scope: this
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing Components and Elements. The `afterrender` event listener is set on the Image Component, and receives the Component itself as the first argument (that you named `el` instead, incorrectly).

Then, in the `afterrender` listener, you retrieve the main DOM element for that Component, which happens to be an `<img>` tag, and set `click` listener on the *element* object, which is an instance of `Ext.dom.Element`.

The `click` event [signature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-click) is not what you expect; the first argument is an `Ext.util.Event` object that does not have a `fireEvent` method. Hence the error.

I would suggest looking up event signatures in the docs before using them. Also try to add a `debugger` statement before the line that blows up, and see what variables are passed in and what is going on. Using Chrome or Firefox debugger can be immensely helpful here.

Comment: If I could know how to pass the outside scope into the on click handler, then I think I could call fireEvent off the image. How do I pass a scope into that handler?

Comment: @GregLafrance See my blog post: http://nohuhu.org/development/dom-event-handling-in-ext-js-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, though I am wondering if this is the best way to do it.

I fire the custom event via the image, and then listen for that event on the image as well in the controller.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'image',
        itemId: 'graphiteChartCPU',
        src: '',
        listeners:{
            'afterrender':function (comp) {
                comp.getEl().on('click', function (el) {
                    this.fireEvent('cpuchartclicked');
                }, this);
            }
        }
    }
]


'myContainer image':
{
    'cpuchartclicked': me.onChartClicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must bind to the image element like that:

```
{
    xtype: 'image',
    itemId: 'graphiteChartCPU',
    src: '',
    listeners: {
      el: {
          click: function() {
          console.log("Click");
          }
      }
    }
}
```

it solve my problem in ext5